# Banner div has a litle space on left and right margin which causes this div to be a little larger than the above header div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have header div with a menu and below I have a banner div.  In the banner div I have a search div with a background-color red and I dont understnad why this div with this red background color is not aligned with the logo and menu items above. There is a little space at the left of the banner div and at the right of the banner div which causes this banner div to become a little larger than the header div above. Do you know why this little space is appearing? It seems that the space is more evident as the width increases.

css:

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
}




input,
select,
textarea,
button {
  padding: 15px;

  width: 100%;
}

select,
input,
button {
  border: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:#94a3a8;

}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}

a img {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;

}

.content {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 30px;
}




.Header{
  padding: 15px;
}

.Header, .main_nav{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.title{
  flex-grow:1;
}

.title a{
  color:red;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

.main_nav{
  background-color:red;
}

.nopaddingright:0;

.main_nav li{
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.main_nav a{
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  color:brown;
}

.main_nav a:hover{
  color:brown;
}

.create{
  border:2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  color:red !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.create:hover{
  border:2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  color:white !important;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 4px;
}


/*************** BANNER *****************/

.Banner{
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;

}

.search{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.input{
  background-color: #fff;
}

.search select{
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.search_form{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 0;
}



.Banner__search_form_element{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.Banner__search_form_element_search{
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9ujbyo7b/2/

Comment: I was working on a solution to your post earlier. Here is a fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/28d28n42/3/

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can you give an answer to accept it?

Comment: @ovokuro You were asked to post your above sample as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of approaching the layout you want...

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

input,
select,
textarea,
button {
  padding: 15px;
  /*width: 100%;*/
}

select,
input,
button {
  border: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}

a img {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Header,
.header__inner,
.main_nav,
.Banner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__inner,
.search {
  /* change this value as you need and target it with media queries */
  width: 90%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.title a {
  color: $color-primary;
  display: inline-block;
  /* padding: 15px; */
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

.main_nav li {
  padding: 15px;
}

.main_nav li:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.main_nav {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main_nav a {
  flex-direction: column;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  color: gray;
}

.create {
  padding: 10px;
  color: red;
  border-radius: 4px;
}


/** BANNER */

.Banner {
  background-color: gray;
  /* remove the padding to left and right */
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.search {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
}

.search select {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

form {
  font-size: 0;
}

.search_form {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /*
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0; */
}

.search_form_element {
  flex: 2;
  /* use margin to separate instead if you prefer */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.search_form_element select,
.search_form_element input {
  width: 100%;
}

.search_form_element:last-of-type {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header class="Header">
  <div class="header__inner">
    <h1 class="title"><a href="">LOGO</a> </h1>
    <ul class="main_nav">
      <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="Banner">
  <div class="search">
    <form class="search_form">
      <div class="search_form_element">
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <input type="search" value="Search">
      </div>
      <div class="search_form_element">
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <select>
          <option selected>Option 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="search_form_element">
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <select>
          <option selected>Option 2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="search_form_element">
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```